# Connecting to my git on a VPS already on my mac, now need to connect via my PC

Tags: windows-7, git

So I installed git on my windows 7 desktop, now I need to connect to my git server.

Do I do the same thing, meaning, create a public/private key on my windows computer and then put the public key on my VPS git server?

Comment: which protocol are you using to connect to your git server, ssh, git or http(s)? Perhaps you should take a look into the Pro Git-book (http://progit.org/book/), chapter 4 deals with git on the server.

Comment: I'm using SSH on my Mac, would like to use the same I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new public and private key to be used by your Windows machine if you'd like, or you may just copy the private key from your Mac and use that.  It's entirely up to you.

Some users prefer to use separate keys for each machine so that they can simply remove that key from the server in the event a machine has been compromised.  Others prefer the convenience of just copying one key to all their machines, and in the rare event one of their machines were compromised they would just remove that key from the server and copy a new key to all their machines.

Comment: so the public key that I put on my server, even if it gets exposed publicly, it isn't a security issue right since the main thing is the private key on my computer?  or is it the other way around?

Comment: @user27449:  Correct.  A public key can only be used to *encrypt* data.  The corresponding private key is necessary to *decrypt* it.  Wikipedia has an excellent article on [Public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) that explains how it all works.